# Chrome extension - Reference JQueryUI for content_script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to reference JQueryUI so I can execute

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('<div id="container"><h1>Error</h1><p>Message</p></div>').dialog({
        title: "Error"
    });
});
```

but I think due to the fact my .js script has no reference it won't work.

Example of my code/files so far:

manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["scripts/alert.js"]
    }
]

"web_accessible_resources": ["embed.html"],
```

embed.html < Contains references ( Example ):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Example">
    <meta name="author" content="Example">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

then alert.js should execute the provided function, example of script:

```
if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('EXAMPLE') > -1){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('<div id="container"><h1>Error</h1><p>Message</p></div>').dialog({
            title: "Error"
        });
    });

}
```

expected output is >

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Comment: Content script runs in context of the webpage and `embed.html` is asset of the chrome extension. What you included in the `embed.html` page is not available for your CS.

Comment: how can I import the stylesheets & script references into my .js file? @elegant-user

Comment: In your `manifest.json` file you can include multiple js and css files. i. e. `"css" : [ "file1.css", "file2.css" ], "js" : [ "file1.js", "file2.js" ],`

Comment: "matches": ["*://*/*"],
   "css": ["css/jquery-ui.css"],
   "js": ["scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"],
   "js": ["scripts//jquery-ui.js"],
   "js": ["scripts/alert.js"]

Done that and still doesn't want to work :/

Comment: Check for errors log in console